# How can I use React Router to change routes from within a component that is also Routed in the Main App.js component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is my App.js that contains the wrapper (home) component and the dashboard I want to redirect to after I successfully sign in.

```
import React from "react";
import Wrapper from "./wrapper";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import "./App.css";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";


function App() {
  return (     
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Wrapper} />
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      </Switch>

  );
}

export default App;
```

and here is the wrapper component that contains the routing I want to do, I simply want to move between sign in and register without leaving the home screen.

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./Nav";
import Signin from "./Signin";
import Info from "./Info";
import Register from "./Register";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const Wrapper = () => {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <Navbar nav={"Home"} navv={"Sign in"} navvv={"Register"} />
      <div className="home-body pa5">
        <Info />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/signin' component={Signin} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Wrapper;
```

the Info component has the Links like so, also the navbar links do the same thing but well.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link,withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const Info = () => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-white-60 br3">
      <p className="f1 center pa3 orange sans-serif">
        Sick? Skip the clinic queue! <br />
        Register now to book an appointment
      </p>
      <div className="ph3">
        <Link
          className="f6 link dim ba ph3 pv2 mb2 dib orange bg-near-white mr4"
          to="/signin"
        >
          Sign in
        </Link>
        <Link
          className="f6 link dim ba ph3 pv2 mb2 dib orange bg-near-white mr4"
          to="/register"
        >
          Register
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Info);
```

I want to be able to click the link in the info that is in my wrapper component and render my sign and login components. right now, when I click either links, it takes me to an empty page/screen. I'm stuck
I know routing inside routed components like this is possible. but I need help

Comment: your main route will be one only, your nesting navigation can be multiples.

Comment: i posted a reference that will help you for understanding your requirement if not let me know will customize nested routing.

Comment: From app.Js, if I remove the `exact`. it almost works well but then the wrapper always renders and my dashboard can't replace it. instead dashboard appears below it. there's got to be a way around

Comment: can you share sandbox so that i could check.

Answer (score 1):

Remove *exact* from `<Route exact path="/" component={Wrapper} />` and move it to the bottom of *Switch*

Comment: I know this is a crude fix, but it does the work. I'd stick it with it for now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it like this. Wrap all sub-components(SignIn or SignUp...) to Wrapper.

and In your Wrapper, add `{this.props.child}`

I prefer this way because I can manage routes in one place.

**App**

```
import React from "react";
import Wrapper from "./wrapper";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import "./App.css";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";


function App() {
  return (     
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Wrapper} />
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          // Add these routes to App
          <Route exact path='/signin' component={Signin} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
      </Switch>

  );
}

export default App;
```

**Wrapper**

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./Nav";
import Signin from "./Signin";
import Info from "./Info";
import Register from "./Register";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const Wrapper = () => {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <Navbar nav={"Home"} navv={"Sign in"} navvv={"Register"} />
      <div className="home-body pa5">
        <Info />
        {...this.props.child} // Replace from <Switch> to this
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Wrapper;
```

**Login or Signin component**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link,withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Wrapper from "./Wrapper";

const Info = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper> // Add this 
        <div className="bg-white-60 br3">
          <p className="f1 center pa3 orange sans-serif">
            Sick? Skip the clinic queue! <br />
            Register now to book an appointment
          </p>
          <div className="ph3">
            <Link
              className="f6 link dim ba ph3 pv2 mb2 dib orange bg-near-white mr4"
              to="/signin"
            >
              Sign in
            </Link>
            <Link
              className="f6 link dim ba ph3 pv2 mb2 dib orange bg-near-white mr4"
              to="/register"
            >
              Register
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Info);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Vlad says, first you need to remove the `exact` from `/`, but also move it down, after the `/dashboard` route, so if the URL is exactly `/dashboard` will match with the `Dashboard` component, otherwise will match with the `Wrapper` component. This should work:

```js
function App() {
  return (     
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/" component={Wrapper} />
      </Switch>

  );
}
```